# Multiple Search box and Dropdown search box in angular 2

Tags: java, angular, rest, angular2-forms

I want to implement a search box in my angular 2 application. As soon as user starts typing some name in the search box , some Java REST service should be called and it should fetch all the names which matches the name typed in the search text box. Note that there is no button , the result should come automatically as soon as user starts typing. The java REST service is already there. I just need to invoke the java REST service when the user starts typing and return the result as a list. For ex:- If I type Jam then all the user whose name starts with Jam should come as a list in the search box.
like james, jamini, jamia and so on.

Once the list of name comes , the user can click on one of the name and his information should be loaded in the current page.

How can I implement such type-on search box  in angular 2? Is there any form search box mechanishm? Can anyone please give me some direction

```
<h3>Find By Brand Name</h3>
<div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="brand" name="brand" class="form-group" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                    <label for="brand">VIN</label> <br>
                    <select (click)="callVin()" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option class="wgtmsr"  class="form-control" 
                        *ngFor="let car of cars"   
                         id="brand" name="brand" ngDefaultControl
                                value= {{car.brand}}  [(ngModel)]="car1.brand">
                            {{car.brand}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="form-group" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                        <label for="year">Year</label> <br>
                        <input name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" type="text" class="form-control" id="year" required
                        [(ngModel)]="car1.year" name="year"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="form-group" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                        <label  for="color">Color</label> <br>
                        <input required minlength="4" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" type="text" class="form-control" id="color" required
                        [(ngModel)]="car1.color" name="color"> 
                </td>


                <td  class="form-group" name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
                            <label for="vin"> Vin Code</label><br>
                            <angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="car1.country" 
                                                    [settings]="settings" 
                                                    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                                                    (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" 
                                                    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" 
                                                    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" name="skills">
                            </angular2-multiselect>     
                        </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Show some code you attempted.!!

Comment: you can try Prime NG autocomplete (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) or ngx bootstrap typeahead (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split your ngModel binding into an input and output-binding by using `(ngModelChange)="onInputChange()`. Because [(ngModel)] does exactly that. It packs both, input and output into one binding. But in your case, it doesn't really fit your needs.

In your code, you can implement the function and call your api:

```
onInputchange() {
    //call rest-api
}
```